# An equation about the Sklyanin bracket

Tags: quantum-groups

I am reading the lecture http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~ruiloja/Poisson2014/EtingofLectures.pdf. I have a question on page 25. I do not know how to calculate the equation (3.2). Thank you very much for any answers.

[image]